# MySQL "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

Tags: mysql

I have the following two queries that execute one after another and work fine (I can't use `on duplicate key update` and hence please ignore that in this discussion as I like to understand why the following behavior happens)

```
delete from mytable where id=1
insert into mytable set id=1, x=2, y=3, ts=unix_timestamp()
```

I then tried to execute these queries in one shot by using semicolons and issuing query like

```
delete from mytable where id=1;insert into mytable set id=1, x=2, y=3, ts=unix_timestamp()
```

This also works fine. However, I start getting  "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" in any queries issued after the above query.

I looked at the MySQL manual and it only explains in terms of results. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html

However, the above queries are for deleting and inserting records and have no result so the above explanation is not helpful.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Below is the table schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (
  x int(10) unsigned default '0',
  id int(10) unsigned default '0',
  y int(20) unsigned default '0',
  ts int(10) unsigned default '0',
  unique KEY (id),
  unique KEY (x, y),
  KEY (x)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: *I can't use on duplicate key update* Try not INSERT .. ODKU but REPLACE INTO. *I start getting "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" in any queries issued after the above query.* AFAIR this means that you must clear the connection from the queries result/status before executing another SQL command.

Comment: EVERY statement should be terminated...You can get away with not doing so if the query is the  last or only statement issued via an ide..nb you haven't told us if you are using and ide , command line or api.

Comment: @Akina, could you explain the clean the connection part.  The code executes thousands of queries one after another and having no issues. The issue only pops up when I use multiple queries in one shot

Comment: @P.Salmom I am using C API `mysql_query`

Comment: @Rahul #1. Check does the method used for the stmts execution supports multiquery (maybe it does not, maybe it needs in some flag to be set..). #2. Multiquery produces multianswer (a collection of stmt statuses), check that you retrieve them all. Most methods won't execute the next query until previous stmt status/rowset is retrieved or discarded.

Comment: As @Akina has mentioned, you should really use **replace**

Comment: @Akina thanks. I will check multianswer part, it might be a possible issue.